# redux security - is it possible to access previous state after state reset?

Tags: security, redux

I've got an app that will keep user specific data in redux that must be cleared when user logs out i.e. next user that logs into the app in the same browser tab, should not be able to access the data.

So, app fetches user specific data from API using redux middleware and then that data is stored as part app state in redux. When user logs out, I dispatch log out action to clear the state:

```
const rootReducer = (state: {}, action: AnyAction) => {
    if( action.type === 'LOG_OUT')
        return {};
    return state;
}
```

All seems good, state is reset to empty state but my question is - when user logs out and user doesn't close browser tab, can someone use dev tools or else to somehow see state before user logged out? Does redux (without using additional persist/history middleware/enhancers) store state somewhere out of the box? or is it all purely in browser memory and when state is reset on logout then previous state is gone and not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no remaining references to the previous state object, then the browser's JS engine will garbage-collect the old state.  That also implies that there would be no variables that the browser's DevTools could inspect.

The Redux core itself does not retain references to prior state objects.

Comment: so for the sake of argument let's say that before setting state to empty object, state before login has been assigned to local variable inside reducer - can I access it from dev tools? and one more question: is it better to reset state by "state = {}" or "state = undefined" or is there other better/recommended way?